# Straight access to xml attribute value with xml inside

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have xml below:

```
<Team>
<Member Name="Alex" Info="&lt;Details Weight=&quot;80&quot; Category=&quot;Fighter&quot; LastFight=&quot;2014-03-01&quot; /&gt;"/>
</Team>
```

I would like to find a way to load Attribute LastFight straight without creating a lot of xmldocuments. Here is my code I use:

```
Dim storagexml As New XmlDocument
storagexml.LoadXml(<Team><Member Name="Alex" Info="&lt;Details Weight=&quot;80&quot; Category=&quot;Fighter&quot; LastFight=&quot;2014-03-01&quot; /&gt;"/></Team>)
Dim tempnodelist As XmlNodeList = storagexml.SelectNodes("Team/Member")
For Each tempnode As XmlNode In tempnodelist
If tempnode.Attributes("Name") IsNot Nothing Then
Dim tempdoc As New XmlDocument
tempdoc.LoadXml(tempnode.Attributes("Info").Value)
Dim tempsel As XmlNode = tempdoc.SelectSingleNode("Info")
If Not tempsel.Attributes("LastFight").Value.Trim() = "" Then
RichTextBox1.AppendText(tempnode.Attributes("Name").Value & " " & tempsel.Attributes("LastFight").Value & vbCrLf)
End If
```

Comment: The biggest question rising to the top in my head at the moment is: why do you have HTML-encoded XML contained inside an attribute of an XML file?  Is this possibly a thing that you can alter instead of trying to pick up the attribute as a string, decoding the HTML-encoded characters and loading it into an XML document?

Comment: Because there will be some text which will contains ampersands inside. To prevent any error decided to put like it is.

Comment: And so you encode the text that potentially contains ampersands, and nothing more than you need to.  Encoding the entire XML document and placing it in a text attribute of another XML document is akin to using a sledgehammer to kill an ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of `Info` attribute is another XML string, so as far as I can see, you can't avoid loading it to another XML abstraction object (f.e `XmlDocument`).

Anyway, you can simplify the code by using LINQ-to-XML. For example using [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) and VB.NET specific feature to access part of XML inline :

```
Dim xml = <Team>
              <Member Name="Alex" Info="&lt;Details Weight=&quot;80&quot; Category=&quot;Fighter&quot; LastFight=&quot;2014-03-01&quot; /&gt;"/>
          </Team>

'notice how to access child element and attribute inline :
'
Dim info = XElement.Parse(xml.<Member>.@Info)
Dim lastFight As String = info.@LastFight
Console.WriteLine(lastFight)
```